# OrderBy before and after Except

Tags: linq

In this query

```
var list = (from t in ObjectCollection
            select t).OrderBy(v => v.Date)
           .Except(from i in items select i.value).OrderBy(v => v.
```

the lambda expression in first OrderBy shows the Date property but in second OrderBy it doesn't. Why?

**Edit #1**
`ObjectCollection` and `items` are of different types. `ObjectCollection` is a collection of students while `items` is a collection of student IDs. Now i see the problem. How would i exclude those students whom IDs are in `items`?

Comment: When you pasted your code, you omitted at least one line. Please add it.

Comment: @Ofer No, it stops where it does because he's expecting `v.Date` and it doesn't appear in Intellisense. bjan, what is in your `ObjectCollection` and `items` collections? If you just end your query after the `Except` does your code compile?

Comment: `i.value` has same type as elements of ObjectCollection?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky No, they are different

Comment: @bjan they should be of same type, if you are applying Except

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your objects in `ObjectCollection` if they have compatible type with values, returned in `i.value` clause. 
I've done a simple test with LinqPad and Visual Studio - and it all works fine. Note that my `v.Date` expression returns instance of `DateTime` and `i.value` also return's an instance of `Datetime`, so `Except` method operates on two compatible sequences of data.
LinqPad version[image]
Visual Studio version
[image]

**EDIT:** You should try to use comething like query given below. `Except` method takes two sequences of the **same** type and removes elements from first sequence, which are present in the second. Thanks @lazyberezovsky I will update my answer by bringing studentToExclude sequence into memory.

```
var studentsToExclude = items.Select(i => i.Value).ToList();

var result = from student in ObjectCollection
             where !studentsToExclude.Contains(student.ID) //I suppose your IDs are stored here
             orderby student.Date
             select student;
```

Comment: But here the types of both lists are not same? I am excluding Students whom IDs are in the second list

Comment: types of lists are NOT the same, but in inner query you select `i.value`, but not `i`

Comment: I have updated an answer to contain a query, that might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to get students with IDs not in items list:

```
var values = items.Select(i => i.Value).ToList();
var list = ObjectCollection.Where(v => !values.Contains(v.ID))
                           .OrderBy(v => v.Date);
```

Or with join (if there are no duplicates in items list):

```
var list = from v in ObjectCollection
           join i in items on v.ID equals i.Value
           orderby v.Date
           select v;
```

Comment: @bjan btw apply `.ToList()` otherwise `from i in items select i.value` will be executed for each student

Comment: +1 Good answer. I've updated my with respect to your notes, if you don't mind, of course